# How to position a view below of "parent" in constraintlayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I tried this:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
```

But it does not work as expected. I want to animate a view off screen, how is this possible with constraintlayout?

Comment: How are you trying to animate the view? The code you show will just statically position the view off screen without animation.